# How to run useState asynchronously

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
const Navbar = () => {

    const [isModalOpen, setisModalOpen] = useState(true)
    const [isLogin, setisLogin] = useState(true)

    const onClose = () =>{
        setisModalOpen(false)
        if(!isLogin){
            setisLogin(true)
        }
    }
    return  (<Modal isOpen={isModalOpen} onClose={() => onClose()} >
    {!isLogin ? 
        <Register />
        :
        <Login setisLogin={() => setisLogin(false)} />
    }
    </Modal>)
}
```

when I call onclose Function component gets re-renders once with the value of login then the modal is closing

Using setTimeout is solving my problem but I think using setTimeout is not a good practice.

```
 const Navbar = () => {

    const [isModalOpen, setisModalOpen] = useState(true)
    const [isLogin, setisLogin] = useState(true)

    const onClose = () =>{
        setisModalOpen(false)
        setTimeout(() => {
            if(!isLogin){
                setisLogin(true)
            }
        }, 300);
   }
    return  (<Modal isOpen={isModalOpen} onClose={() => onClose()} >
    {!isLogin ? 
        <Register />
        :
        <Login setisLogin={() => setisLogin(false)} />
    }
    </Modal>)
}
```

Comment: are your `{}` placed wrong in the snippet you  posted ? because it does not make much sense to return an element from an event handler like `onClose`

Comment: sorry I'll edit it

Comment: useState run asynchronly

Comment: you can use `useEffect` and listen on the `isLogin` if it changes trigger the `setisLogin()` function

Answer (score 2):

There are couple of ways you can achieve this. i am posting the `useEffect` way.

you can use `useEffect` and listen on the `isLogin` if it changes trigger the `setisLogin()` function.

**code**

```
const Navbar = () => {

  const [isModalOpen, setisModalOpen] = useState(true)
  const [isLogin, setisLogin] = useState(true)

  React.useEffect(() => {
     if(!isLogin){
        setisLogin(true);
     }
  },[isModalOpen])

  
  const onClose = () =>{
     setisModalOpen(false)
  }

 return  (<Modal isOpen={isModalOpen} onClose={() => onClose()} >

 {!isLogin ? 
    <Register />
    :
    <Login setisLogin={() => setisLogin(false)} />
  }
 </Modal>)
}
```

useState and setState both are asynchronous in nature already.

Answer (score 0):

Like [Shoyeb Memon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8457255/shoyeb-memon) mentioned, you can use React's `useEffect` hook to "listen" to changes with `isModalOpen` and act upon those changes.

The implementation should look like this:

```js
const onClose = () =>{
   setisModalOpen(false)
}

useEffect(() => {
   if(!isLogin){
      setisLogin(true)
   }
}, [isModalOpen]);
```

This is the way we usually handle this types of situation in React,
where we need to act upon a change in state or in values that we receive asynchronously.